# One colorbar for multiple scatter plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, colorbar

I'm plotting multiple figures of the same variable on one plot using `matplotlib` library. **I'm not looking for a `colorbar` for subplots**, which is the dominant search material. I plot multiple `scatter`s, but the `colorbar` is only set to the values of the last scatter I plot.

Here is the part of the code:

```
plt.scatter(x1, y1, c=z1,cmap='viridis_r',marker='s')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, c=z2,cmap='viridis_r',marker='o')
plt.scatter(x3, y3, c=z3,cmap='viridis_r',marker='^')
plt.colorbar().set_label('Wind speed',rotation=270)
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `plt.colorbar().set_label('Wind speed',rotation=270)` after each `.scatter`?

Comment: Yes, but that adds three colorbars, which is not what I'm looking for. I need one colorbar that includes all the ranges in the plotted scatterplots.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It requires a bit of extra work:

- You have to get the minimum and maximum of the `c`s (the colorbar values)
- You have to `clim` each scatter plot

First the minimum and maximum:

```
zs = np.concatenate([z1, z2, z3], axis=0)
min_, max_ = zs.min(), zs.max()
```

Then the scatter plots with `clim`:

```
plt.scatter(x1, y1, c=z1,cmap='viridis_r',marker='s')
plt.clim(min_, max_)
plt.scatter(x2, y2, c=z2,cmap='viridis_r',marker='o')
plt.clim(min_, max_)
plt.scatter(x3, y3, c=z3,cmap='viridis_r',marker='^')
plt.clim(min_, max_)
plt.colorbar().set_label('Wind speed',rotation=270)
```

For a very simple dataset:

```
x1, x2, x3 = [1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]
y1 = y2 = y3 = [1, 2, 3]
z1, z2, z3 = [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]
```

[image]

Comment: I can't figure out how to do this when working with Axes objects. Axes have no `clim` or `set_clim` methods, and when I try to `get_images()` from the Axes object after doing the scatter plot, I get an empty list (images should have `set_clim`).

Comment: `clim` seems to no longer work with newer matplotlib versions, but it's usage can be replaced with `vmin` and `vmax`, like this: 
`plt.scatter(x1, y1, c=z1, vmin=min_, vmax=max_)`, followed by the `plt.colorbar` as in the current example.

Answer (score 7):

`scatter` has a `norm` argument. Using the same `norm` for all scatters ensures that the colorbar produced by any of the plots (hence also the last) is the same for all scatter plots.

The `norm` can be a `Normalize` instance, to which minimum and maximum value are set and which produces a linear scaling in between. Of course you can also use any other norm provided in `matplotlib.colors` like `PowerNorm`, `LogNorm`, etc.

```
mini, maxi = 0, 2  # or use different method to determine the minimum and maximum to use
norm = plt.Normalize(mini, maxi)
plt.scatter(x1, y1, c=z1,cmap='viridis_r',marker='s', norm=norm)
plt.scatter(x2, y2, c=z2,cmap='viridis_r',marker='o', norm=norm)
plt.scatter(x3, y3, c=z3,cmap='viridis_r',marker='^', norm=norm)
plt.colorbar().set_label('Wind speed',rotation=270)
```