# Plot data from two DataFrame with only one colorbar in a scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two `DataFrame` for two different datasets that contain columns `RA`,`Dec`, and `Vel`. I need to plot them to a same scatter plot and show one `colorbar` instead of two. There's similar question using pure `matplotlib` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106912/one-colorbar-for-multiple-scatter-plots), but I need to do it using scatter plot function from `pandas`. Here's my experiment so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.DataFrame({'RA':np.random.randint(-100,100,5),
         'Dec':np.random.randint(-100,100,5),'Vel':np.random.randint(-20,10,5)})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'RA':np.random.randint(-100,100,5),
         'Dec':np.random.randint(-100,100,5),'Vel':np.random.randint(-10,20,5)})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 10))


data1.plot.scatter(x='RA',y='Dec',c='Vel',cmap='rainbow',
            marker='^',ax=ax,label='Methanol',vmin=-20, vmax=20)
data2.plot.scatter(x='RA',y='Dec',c='Vel',cmap='rainbow',
            marker='o',ax=ax,label='Water',vmin=-20, vmax=20)

ax.set_xlabel('$\Delta$RA (arcsec.)')
ax.set_ylabel('$\Delta$Dec. (arcsec.)')
ax.set_title('Maser Spot')
ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.legend(loc=2)
```

Using this code, I managed to plot two `DataFrame` into one scatter plot. But it shows two colorbars as you can see here:
[Test Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z59Xi.png).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `colorbar = False` in the first plot.

The final code will be :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.DataFrame({'RA':np.random.randint(-100,100,5),
         'Dec':np.random.randint(-100,100,5),'Vel':np.random.randint(-20,10,5)})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'RA':np.random.randint(-100,100,5),
         'Dec':np.random.randint(-100,100,5),'Vel':np.random.randint(-10,20,5)})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 10))


data1.plot.scatter(x='RA',y='Dec',c='Vel',cmap='rainbow',
            marker='^',ax=ax,label='Methanol',vmin=-20, vmax=20,
                  colorbar=False)
data2.plot.scatter(x='RA',y='Dec',c='Vel',cmap='rainbow',
            marker='o',ax=ax,label='Water',vmin=-20, vmax=20)

ax.set_xlabel('$\Delta$RA (arcsec.)')
ax.set_ylabel('$\Delta$Dec. (arcsec.)')
ax.set_title('Maser Spot')
ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.legend(loc=2)
```

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for pointing that out. I don't realize that they are already in the same scale.